# cannot compare if more or less than the current time Calendar.MONTH

Tags: android

I'm trying here check the date to put the appropriate separator, but the problem is that when comparing the Calendar.Months, and the other checks work fine

```
if   (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) > Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) && calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) > Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) ||
                        (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) < Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) && calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) > Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)) ||
                        (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) && calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) > Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR))||
                        (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) && calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) > Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH)&&calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) == Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)))
                        {
                newTask.setDateStatus(ModelSeparator.TYPE_FUTURE);
                if (!adapter.containsSeparatorFuture) {
                    adapter.containsSeparatorFuture = true;
                    separator = new ModelSeparator(ModelSeparator.TYPE_FUTURE);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Future",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

Comment: If you're just trying to figure out if one date comes before or after another, why don't you just use one of the `Calendar#before()`, `Calendar#after()`, or `Calendar#compareTo()` methods?